# Оптимальный подход проверки интернет подключения в сетевом приложении

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Хотелось бы узнать как оптимальней всего будет реализовать проверку интернет соединения в сетевом приложении.
Я использую **Retrofit2**, каждых n секунд мне необходимо опрашивать сервер.

реализую `okhttp3.Interceptor`

```
@Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
            throw new NetworkException();
        }
}
```

когда выполняю запрос на сервер,  `retrofit2. Callback<T>` в методе обратного вызова
`onFailure(Call<MyModel> call, Throwable t)` проверяю  `if (t instanceof NetworkException)` 
то единожды вывожу сообщение о отсутствии интернет соединения.

Но меня смущает то, что при кажом опросе сервера мне необходимо выполнять проверку isNetworkAvailable, в которой
"дергать" `ConnectivityManager getActiveNetworkInfo()`, проверять `instanceof` в `onFailure()`....
поэтому я не уверен в том что это наилучший подход.

Подход с определением **broadcastreceiver`a**, слушающего события изменения статуса сети мне кажется более оптимальным, 
событиеориентированным, но он считается deprecated. 
Поэтому хотелось выяснить, как реализовать проверку интернет соединения наиболее оптимально.

Comment: А exception, который retrofit возвращает по умолчанию не подходит (Timeout или HostNotFound)?

Comment: @eugeneek да,возвращает java.net.UnknownHostException.
Если я опрашиваю сервер, допустим, каждые 2 секунды, мне пришел данный экзепшн, я отобразил уведомление о отсутствии сети. Хорошая ли это практика продолжать выполнять запросы к апи?

Comment: может есть какой-либо best practice на эту тему?

Comment: Зависит от конкретного сценария. В вашем случае конечно смысла продолжать посылать запрос нет. Лучше слушать изменение состояния сети. Кстати, где сказано, что этот метод деприкейтед? На сколько я помню, там только изменился механизм регистрации ресивера.

Comment: ага. спасибо. я это, получается, недочитал

Comment: Не вижу смысла вообще в проверках доступности сети, т.к на момент проверки он может быть, а во время выполнения запроса он может пропасть. Просто обрабатывайте соответствующие исключения.

Comment: @temq если необходимо обращаться к апи каждых 2 секунды, вы считаете правильным продолжать выполнять запрос  с таким интервалом при отсутствии подключения? "обработка соответствующих исключений"  - я так понимаю, предполагает такой сценарий.
мне кажется более логичным ориентироваться на события : нет сети - прекратить запросы. появилась - возобновить. но это сугубо моя точка зрения, поэтому я и задал данный вопрос чтобы узнать как будет правильней

Comment: Кстати, опрашивать сеть каждые 2 секунды не кажется хорошей идеей. Юзер будет недоволен количеством трафика и разрядом батарейки. Опишите задачу, которую вы решаете таким способом и, может кто подскажет более оптимальное решение.

Comment: @ eugeneek 2 секунды это я так, к примеру.

Comment: задача : обновлять положение объекта на гугл карте с интервалом 10 сек

Comment: @Jackky777 ну так если словили ошибку, то и не отправляйте данные на сервер, а запустите какой либо механизм отслеживания состояния сети. Так же очень часто любят ставить такую проверку и перед обычным одиночным запросом.

Answer (score 1):

Самое лучшее решение: перестать изобретать велосипеды и части операционной системы. Пользователь сам знает что у него есть. Просто делайте свою работу, ради чего приложение написано.

Если есть сеть, то это еще не значит, что ваш хост доступен, к примеру, из-за перегруженности сети. Просто напишите сообщение "Не могу сконнетиться" и все. До кучи на один пермишшен меньше.

Если опрашиваете какой-то ресурс с высокой частотой, то <s>самое время сменить раб</s>обязательно корректно обрабатывайте ошибки и говорите пользователю. Можно даже сделать настройку вида "При проблемах с обновлением: остановиться / продолжать 1 минуту / продложать всегда". Как и когда сеть появится, что нужно сделать - ЭТО **НЕ ВАШЕ ДЕЛО**, пользователь и его ОС сами это решат, а подобные велосипеды лишь приводят к тому, что надо будет передергивать подключения/проводки/выходить и заходить.